# Designing a code appropriate for the transmission channel

Tags: coding-theory, binary

I need to design binary linear n,k- code for a transmission channel fulfilling the following requirements:

1. Probability of error during transmission for one bit is 0,1, or 10%.
2. The code must ensure transmission probability of an entire word of 0,999, or   99,9%.

Is there a way to design a code based on these requirements? Currently I'm just guessing which code can fit the requirements and testing it afterwards, which seems inefficient.
Thank you

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking at the BSC with 0.1 error probability? And, are you limited in what rates you're allowed to transmit at? (Otherwise, try to think/explain why a simple repetition code doesn't suffice; that should bring the context into more focus.)

Comment: Thank you for responding, it is a problem professor gave us at encryption class. Yes, (7,1) repetition code suffices, and is simple to figure out, and probably what the professor had in mind, should have seen that. But is there some way to find a better code for the task, less redundant one? Other than testing codes that come to mind at random. In case simple repetition is not what he ment. Thank you